# Do I need to rebuild my VAO if I need to change a VBO?

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering my scene by constructing or modifying a buffer that I give to `glBufferData`. My understanding of Vertex Array Objects is that they allow me to skip the manual binding of all of the VBOs I am using. Is this still the case when I update my buffer all the time?

Can I bind my VAO, call `glBufferData` to update the vertices and indices (the only two VBOs I have at the moment), and then render?

Can I use memory mapping with the VBO's? Then I could bind VAO, modify buffer, then render?

What exactly does the VAO do? Is its function simply that of a shortcut which stores and automates the binding of vertex attributes to my VBO's? Does it take ownership of either the data or the bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to test this, but from my understanding VBOs are given IDs when generated and a VAO only references each vertex attrib along with the VBO ID it's using. You should be able to call `glBufferData` or `glBufferSubData`. I'm not sure if memory mapping just before the draw call would work, but you could certainly do things between binding the VAO and drawing. A VAO doesn't lock the VBOs or restrict access to them.

In general, a VAO just stores attributes and all their settings (bound VBO, stride, offset, etc.) and automatically binds the attributes when bound. Until you call `glBindVertexArray(0);`, all vertex attributes are tied to the bound VAO.

Comment: So the VAO does not affect which VBO I have bound? I'll need to bind them and call `glBufferData` on them.

Comment: @Robert Rouhani  Considering that your vertex layout is identical for most draws I find it quite ridiculous that you have to store a different set of vertex attributes for each VBO. I looked for a while to try to avoid this but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice The amount of space taken should be minimal (on the order of bytes), the extra GL calls to bind different attributes should not be your bottleneck. The closest thing you'd want is instancing, anything else would be unnecessary/premature optimization in my opinion.

Comment: @Robert Rouhani Nah, I'm just saying, you're right. It's just hard to believe that seeing as though they're not changed often at all, the vertex layout isn't some global state or they could be bound to the VBO. Am I doing something wrong? Because every time I bind another VBO, I need to call glVertexAttribPointer and glEnableVertexAttribArray every single time. I think that's because the vertex layout is bound to the VAO and it changes when binding a VBO. I have no clue if it's better to have a VAO for each VBO in that case.